# Drush doesn't export command result as file

Tags: drupal-8, drush

I would to export result from a command run by drush but it doesn't work.
This command create an empty file:

```
drush @sited8bl.preprod ms > ~/www/XXX/exports-bruts/$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)-migrationsBL.txt --debug
```

This debug message let think the command isn't found:

```
[debug] Done with bootstrap max in Application::find(): trying to find ms again. [4.39 sec, 31.8 MB]
```

On another server (multisite) it works, the hosting say there is a drush issue.
If someone can help me on this

Thanks

Comment: If it works on another server, what is different on both of them? Same shell? Same everything?

Comment: the non working server is the hosted one. But they tell me that isn't a permission issue or something.